# Is it an offence against Varuna if I urinate/defecate in toilet water?

Tags: karma, sin, manu-smriti, varuna

Is that something that will create bad karma or lead to Hell?
In reference to Manusmriti, chapter 4, verses 44—56.

Comment: As far as I know ,  Manusmriti is to be implemented only in Satyuga .Parashara smriti is to implemeneted in Kaliyuga.

Comment: @river i think similarly statement is even present in other Dharma Shastra - Gautama (9.45.13), Āpastamba Dharmasūtra (1.30.18) & Yājñavalkya (1.134)

Comment: @river also Parashara has called Manu as “**knower of all shastras**” (parashar smriti 9/51) so you can't ignore a verse from manusmriti just because it's "not applicable in this Kaliyuga"